# how to cancel one of the pending http request from many angular 8

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular8

I have an implementation for a file upload api using drag and drop multiple files. I am making a call within the for loop as below

```
uploadFile(file:any[]) {
    file.forEach((file, index)=>{
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('report_file', file);
      this.fileService.uploadFile(this.configurations.uploadUrl, formData)
      .subscribe(fileResp=>{
        console.log('file', fileResp);
      }, error=>{
        console.log('error while uploading files', error);
      });
  });
}
```

This works while uploading. However, I have a requirement to be able to cancel one of the pending file if needed. so, how do I cancel a particular http request if user is opting to cancel that upload? for the bulk cancel I can do unsubscribe to my observable but in this case I need to make others still be uploading.

Comment: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html perhaps. A bit rusty now..

Comment: How is the user supposed to cancel an upload? A button click of something like that?

Comment: yes, there will be a cancel icon next to the progress bar for the user to cancel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```js
const files$ = from(files);

files$.pipe(
  mergeMap(
    file => this.fileService.uploadFile(/* ... */).pipe(
      takeUntil(fromEvent(getButtonThatCorrespondsToFile(crtFile), 'click').pipe(take(1)))
    )
  )
)

function getButtonThatCorrespondsToFile (): HTMLButtonElement { }
```

- `mergeMap` - will allow you to start making a request for each file at the same time
- `takeUntil` - attached to the request's observable of each file; makes sure that when a button that corresponds to a certain file is clicked, it will cancel the current request

Now I guess a small problem is how you get a button that corresponds to a file, but I think that wouldn't be too difficult. You could use, for example, `@ViewChildren` to get all the buttons, and by using the index in the `mergeMap`'s projection function(2nd argument; `mergeMap((val, idx) => ...)`), you could identify a certain file.

Comment: Thanks! @Andrei Gătej I will try this out!

Comment: Is there a way to have a OR condition for takeUntil?  something like 
` fromEvent(getButtonThatCorrespondsToFile(crtFile), 'click') || this.ngUnsubscribe`

Comment: I think there is a way, try to use the defer operator: defer(() => condition ? a$ : b$)

Comment: Thanks, I chained the TakeUntil twice to figure that out.